# Redirect is not working in Codeigniter on real server. Error reporting in on but not showing any error

Tags: codeigniter

I have Codeigniter 2 installed on my server. redirect is not working on the login page. I can provide the URL.

This is my controller file of login. I have set the error reporting on but not displaying any error. Kindly help me with this. The script is taken from truebus.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
        $this->load->model('AdminLogin_model');
        $this->load->model('Settings_model');
        $this->load->library('session');

        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin')) { 
            redirect(site_url('bus_details/view_busdetails'));
        }
    }
}
public function index(){

        $template['page_title'] = "Login";
        if(isset($_POST)) {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            // redirect(base_url().'Bus_details/view_busdetails');
            redirect(site_url('bus_details/view_busdetails'));
        }
        }
        $this->load->view('login-form');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't include URL helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

you should include in controller

$this->load->helper('url);
redirect()